# Webpack Style-loader media tag for printing

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have a webpack loader that includes css , and i want to add another css link with a media attribute for printing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="file.js">
```

I tried to modifiy addStyles.js of the style-loader module and added at the options object the media property to read the query params passed to style-loader

```
    loaders: [
  {
    test: "print.css",
    loaders: [
      'style-loader?media=print', // here i pass the print value to media  in options object
      'css-loader?sourceMap'
    ]
  },
```

The problem here is that even if i pass the media params for a single file it will generate this on all the included css files , how can i avoid this?

here you can find the complete loader

```
  loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.global\.css$/,
    loaders: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader?sourceMap'
    ]
  },

  {
    test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
    loaders: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader?modules&sourceMap&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
    ]
  },

  { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
  { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
  { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
  { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file' },
  { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
]
```

Comment: Hi Sam, good question. My guess is that to generate a separate css file you need to setup a separate output file, perhaps via ExtractTextPlugin.  But you could also include the CSS inline; after all it's just an `@media` rule/query.